# Restore Safari Favourites Bar from Time Machine

Tags: safari, backup, restore

I've had a strange occurrence I just spotted today - my Favourites bar on Safari has for some totally unknown reason partially reverted to a version from several months ago.
It has restored headers [& their contents] I have long-since deleted.

The headers I have most recently been using appear to be current - I don't change them often, but I can see sites in there that I've definitely only added recently.
So, the issue appears to be that old, deleted menus have returned from who knows where. Current menus seem OK.

As I have both Time Machine and Backblaze, going back over a year, I'm guessing all I need is to restore one or two prefs files from my backup to be back to 'normal'.

Does anyone know which file[s] & where they live?